# SVG cursor not responding to a tags

Tags: javascript, svg, cursor

I've created a custom SVG cursor and having trouble with it responding to links. You can see from the example below you're not able to open the link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZymZK

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $(".custom-cursor").position({
    my: "center center",
    of: e,
    collision: "fit"
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
     cursor: url(http://chrishawkins.us/blank.cur), none;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: none;
}
a:hover {
 cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="pointer" height="50" width="50">
  <polygon points="1,1 49,10 20,20 10,49"> 
    <!-- coordinates are in x,y format -->
    <!-- points go clockwise around the polygon -->
</svg>
  
  
  <a href="bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">bbc</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give the below property to the selector #pointer:

```
position: relative;
```

It should work.